# Check if string has unique characters

Tags: c++, algorithm

I know how to check if the string has unique characters , but i want to to display NOT UNIQUE even if they are of different cases

eg - My algorithm

string = "dhAra" => UNIQUE

What i think would be better is that it displays NOT UNIQUE because it has 'a' twice

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
string str = "dhAra";
bool arr[128] = {0};

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length() ; i++)
{
 int val = str[i];  //i think something needs to change here 
 cout << val << endl; 

 if(arr[val])
 { 
  cout << " not unique" ; 
  return 0; 
 }
 else
 { arr[val] = 1;} 
}
cout << "unique" ; 
return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: There are `std::unique` and `std::unique_copy` algorithms you might find useful.

Comment: For ASCII characters only?

Comment: Yes for ASCII char only. But the problem is even multiple spaces are recognized as duplicates. I'm gonna have to find a way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `toupper` or `tolower` on all characters to make sure that you catch duplicates that are different only in their case:

```
int val = toupper(str[i]); // tolower would be fine as well
```

As a side note, a canonical way of assigning `true` to a `bool` in C++ is

```
arr[val] = true; // rather than arr[val] = 1
```

although both ways work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the correct way of what of wanted I to do,

```
// find if the string contains unique characters 
// uses extra space 

#include<iostream>

int main()
{
string str = "dhAr guptqwe fsklm";
bool arr[128] = {false};

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length() ; i++)
{
 int val = toupper(str[i]);

 if(val == 32)
 continue; 

 if(arr[val])
 { 
  cout << " not unique" ; 
  return 0; 
 }
 else
 { arr[val] = true;} 
}
cout << "unique" ; 
return 0 ; 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package geeksforgeeks;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
import java.util.*;

public class unique_char {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void quicksort(char array[], int p, int r)
{
    System.out.println("hello");
    if(r - p < 1)
          return;
    int pivot = p;
    int i = p + 1;
    int j = r;

    while(i < j)
    {
        while(array[i] > array[p] && i < r)
            i++;
        while(array[j] > array[p] && j > p)
            j--;

        if(i < j)
            swap(array,i,j);
    }
    swap(array,pivot,j);

    quicksort(array,p,j-1);
    quicksort(array,j+1,r);

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char line[] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    quicksort(line,0,line.length-1);

    //System.out.print(line);

    for(int i=0; i<line.length-1; i++)
    {
          if(line[i] == line[i+1])
               System.out.println("string dont have all char unique");
               break;
    }

}

private static void swap(char[] array, int pivot, int j)
{
    char t = array[pivot];
    array[pivot] = array[j];
    array[j] = t;
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The latest answer posted by Dharag pretty much works, except a small change that gives the final answer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int counter = 0;
string str = "dhAr guptqwe fsklm";
bool arr[128] = { false };

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    int val = toupper(str[i]);

    if (val == 32)
        continue;

    if (arr[val])
    {
        cout << "not unique\n";
        counter++;
        break;
        //return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[val] = true;
    }
}

if (counter < 1) {
    cout << "unique\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

I have used a counter variable and incremented when a matched char is found. Check the value of counter to check if the entire string is unique. Also, once the match is found in the string, we can exit the rest of the process to increase the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

//Method signature to determing if the string are unique
bool hasUniqueCharacters(string str);

int main(void){
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    if(hasUniqueCharacters(str)){
        cout<< " The Input string has all unique character" ;
    }
    else{
        cout<< " The input string does not have unique characters";
    }
    return 0;
}

/// <summary>
///     Implements the method hasUniqueCharacters to check if the input string has unique characters
/// </summary>
/// <Assumption>
///     This method assumes that all the characters in the input string are ASCII characters and the method uses a boolean array and makes the index of the ASCII equivalent field true. and traverses the whole string to veirfy if there are no duplicates.
/// </Assumption>
/// <param name="str">
///    This is the input string which needs to be checked.
/// </param>
/// <return datatype = boolean>
///     This method would return true if all the characters are unique in the input string.
/// </return datatype>

bool hasUniqueCharacters(string str){
    int strLength = str.size();
    bool characters[256];
    //Initializing all the index values in characters array to false.
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
        characters[i] = false;
    }
    //We are verifying if the character is already present in the array else making it true and perform this operation untill the string is complete.
    for(int i=0;i<strLength-1;i++){
        if(characters[int(str[i])])
            return false;
        else 
            characters[int(str[i])] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```